# Unable to sendkeys with html for hyperlink

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium

I'm trying to include the following line in a test but this does not seem to work. There's a red X before this line with the comment:

Multiple markers at this line

> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
>        MethodInvocation
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

```
     driver.findElement(By.id("ID")).sendKeys("<a href="http://www.test.nl" target="_blank">http://www.test.nl</a>");
```

I've tried looking up ways to include HTML in a sendKeys function but can't find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Using `Eclipse`, `Seleniumwebdriver`, `java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `"` must be after escape character. This error is due to missing escape characters (`\`).

Try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ID")).sendKeys("<a href=\"http://www.test.nl\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.test.nl</a>");
```